# Query the first letter of names using data from another table SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm really hoping someone can help me. This problem has defeated me so far.  I have a table containing a count of how many times each person has attended a meeting. I need to use the first letter of the person with the most attendances to query names in another table which start with the same letter. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Please post the Table structure for that two tables to help you in this regard

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this if you have a table of employee names with a total column:

```
select *
  from other_tab ot
       inner join (select substr(emp_name, 1, 1) first_letter, 
                          rank() over (order by attendences desc) rnk
                     from emp_meeting_count) mc 
               on ot.name like mc.first_letter ||  '%'
 where mc.rnk = 1;
```

i used `rank()` as it may be possible that two or more employees have the most attendances

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2951d/1

Comment: +1.  Something like  max(substr(name,1,1)) keep ( dense_rank first  order by attendances desc, name asc ) would be more efficient, if you don't have to worry about ties in attendance.

Answer (score 0):

YOU Can use Like operator to acheive this scenerio

The SQL WILDCARDS can be used to search data within a table.

SQL wildcards are used with SQL LIKE operator.

```
Syntax

SELECT [* | column_list]

FROM <table_name> WHERE ( column_name)

LIKE <wildcards>;
```

Example

```
SELECT cust_code,cust_name,cust_city,cust_country  
FROM customer  
WHERE cust_name LIKE 'S%';
```

Please refer the link below for information

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/wildcards-like-operator/wildcards-like-operator.php

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

will something like this work? i am writing in assumption

table_abc contains person name and count of attendance 
table_xyz is the another table to check

```
select result_xyz.* from 
(select substr(name,1,1) valueA from table_abc 
where attendance_count=(select max(attendance_count) from table_abc)) result_abc, 
(select substr(name,1,1) valueB,name from table_xyz) result_xyz
where result_abc.valueA=result_xyz.valueB
```